# Is there a WP8 Panel control with background image property

Tags: c#, controls, windows-phone-8.1

Developing Windows Phone 8 app.

If this was a winform app I would add a panel control, set the background image and put controls inside that panel.

I am trying to find the equivalent in WP8. Namely a background image for my panel with the ability to place child controls inside.

Is there something like this for WP8?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush) will help you, you can set a Background of a Grid and put controls there, other panels...

Comment: thank you. Wil have alook at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a background image on a Grid

In XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="myimage.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <!--Your controls here-->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting there :)